# How to auto generate resolv.conf on Centos 6.5

Tags: networking, networkmanager, dhcp, centos, resolv.conf

I just installed CentOS 6.5 and configured the following files:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=aa:bb:dd:dd:ee:ff
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=adfddfaf-9sda-adse-dfs4-asdfsdfdfg97
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network`

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.IM
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
```

When I reboot the computer, `ifconfig eth0` shows an IP address but the `resolv.conf` file is empty.  All it says inside is `search IM`.  There are no `nameservers` listed in the file.

However, after bootup, if I do `dhclient -r` to release the IP address and then type `dhclient eth0` to get an IP address, `resolv.conf` is populated correctly with my DNS name servers.

Why isn't this happening automatically from my configuration files?  I thought `dhcp` enabled in my `ifcfg-eth0` file should take care of this.

The CentOS documentation says setting `NETWORKING=yes` starts networking at boot time: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take the `.IM` off of the hostname, and try something other than localhost, or omit it altogether.

Comment: Incidentally the script responsible for setting the file up along with the entire eth0 device is done out of here: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `NM_CONTROLLED=no` and stop the Network Manager daemon and prevent it from restarting during boots:

```
/sbin/service   NetworkManager stop
/sbin/chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

Now populate your `/etc/resolv.conf` file according to your needs.

Otherwise, set `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` and leave the NetworkManager daemon running.  In this case, add up to two DNS entries in the `ifcfg-eth*` file as, for example:

```
DNS1=10.11.12.13
DNS2=10.11.12.14
DOMAIN=mydomain.net
```

This will populate the `/etc/resolv.conf` file for you.

Comment: The `resolv.conf` file should still be getting updated irregardless. I have many headless systems without NetworkManager that get their contents from the DHCP server just fine. So something else is up here.

Comment: When NetworkManager is being used, it's responsible for updating `/etc/resolv.conf` using the data from DHCP. When it's not being used, the `network` service runs `dhclient` which in turn is responsible for writing the `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Irregardless of your use of "irregardless", I'll have to disagree with you; 

> PEERDNS - initscripts interpret PEERDNS=no to mean "never touch resolv.conf". NetworkManager interprets it to say "never add automatic (DHCP, PPP, VPN, etc.) nameservers to resolv.conf".   


Supply the `PEERDNS=yes` line to the specific `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-` file to automatically update the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

From the `NM-SETTINGS-IFCFG-RH ()` man-page:

> PEERDNS - initscripts interpret PEERDNS=no to mean "never touch
>   resolv.conf". NetworkManager interprets it to say "never add automatic
>   (DHCP, PPP, VPN, etc.) nameservers to resolv.conf".

Supply the PEERDNS=yes line to the specific /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg- file to automatically update the /etc/resolv.conf file.

```
    PEERDNS=yes
```

Additionally, if you **don't** want the interface to be controlled with NetworkManager add the following line:

```
    NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

However, the first line should be sufficient regardless of whether the interface is controlled by NetworkManager or not.